# Python pandas - Adding a list to a dataframe cell if multiple conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, conditional-statements

I have been trying to add lists to cells in a dataframe. Simplified the dataframe looks something like this:

| Participant | Session | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 2 |  |

Most participants only have one recorded session, but some have two. I want to add each list to a single cell of column C, corresponding to the right participant & session ID. So, after adding the list to the right participant (e.g 4) and session (e.g 1) it should look like this:

| Participant | Session | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 1 | [1, 2, 3] |
| 4 | 2 |  |

My first attempt was using conditions with df.loc()

```
df.loc[((df['participant'] == '4') & (df['session'] == 1)), 'Column_C'] = [1, 2, 3]
```

However, this gave the following error: 'ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable'

In other threads it was mentioned that in order to set lists/tuples/arrays in a singular dataframe cell, you need to use df.at(). However, I couldn't figure out how to include the conditions when using .at()

Other threads have also mentioned that the dtype of the column has to be set as object. However, even after making sure the column is set as object, I still get the same error.

Is there anyway I can add a list/tuple/array to a pandas dataframe cell while still including conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Participant':[1,2,3,3,4,4], 'Session' :[1,1,1,2,1,2]})
df['Column_C']=np.nan
df['Column_C'] = df['Column_C'].mask((df['Participant']==4) & (df['Session'] == 1) ,pd.Series([[1,2,3]]*df.shape[0]))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply` method, applied function for your specific example could look like that:

```
def insert_list(row):
    # your condition for ROW
    if row['Participant'] == 4 and row['Session'] == 1:
        return [1, 2, 3]
    else:
        return row['Column_C'] # wont change a cell if condition is not satisfied
```

Then simply apply this function to update the column 'Column_C' values:

```
df['Column_C'] = df.apply(insert_list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant solution but it works.
First use df.index to find the index of the row that meets your condition.
Then you can use df.at to set the list.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

idx = df.index[(df['col1'] == 2) & (df['col2'] == 4)].tolist()

df.at[idx[0], 'col3']=[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Column_C']=df['Participant'].transform(lambda x: df.query('Participant == @x')['Session'].tolist())
```